# How to install pycurl on Elastic beanstalk (django+celery+sqs)

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, pycurl

I am using SQS for my Django/Celery application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything works great on my localhost, but I when I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk I always get this error regarding pycurl:

File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 43, in **init**
    raise ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.')

I still got this error, even I the deployment history shows that it has been installed already:
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl==7.43.0.1 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 21))

Also, when I import it, there is no pycurl version listed:

> > > import pycurl
> > >       pycurl.version
> > >       'libcurl/7.53.1 NSS/3.28.4 zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.6.2 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.4.2 nghttp2/1.21.1'

compared to pycurl documentation:

> > > import pycurl
> > >       pycurl.version
> > >       '**PycURL/7.19.3** libcurl/7.33.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.7'

Could anyone please help here?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you are using aws linux for beanstalk, how are you installing libcurl-devel?

Comment: Yes, I am using amazon linux, I manually downloaded licurl-devel 7.53 installation package and uploaded to my instance and installed with yum .

Comment: actually,  libcurl-devel is available from yum repository

Comment: Elastic beanstalk is very difficult to use, I have decided to use EC2 and ubuntu. It's much easier with ubuntu.